# Match value excel from bottom to top (vba)

Tags: excel, vba

Now I have code as below.
But now I want to check match ws.Columns(2) from bottom to top (in ws.Columns(2), 0)

```
Chk = Application.Match(Data(i, 2),** ws.Columns(2)**, 0)
```

Full code as below.

```
Sub Test()
Dim Data, Chk, ws As Worksheet, i As Long
Set ws = Workbooks("Summary.xlsx").Sheets("Correct")
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Correct").Cells(1).CurrentRegion
    Data = .Value
    For i = 2 To UBound(Data)
        Chk = Application.Match(Data(i, 2), ws.Columns(2), 0)
        If IsError(Chk) Then
            .Cells(i, 1).Resize(, 4).Copy ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2)
        ElseIf ws.Cells(Chk, 6) = "OK" Or ws.Cells(Chk, 6) <> "" Then
            .Cells(i, 1).Resize(, 4).Copy ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2)
        End If
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Please guide me for solve it.
Thank you

Comment: Are you looking for `For i = UBound(Data) To 2 Step -1`?

Comment: Try [FIND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) with the `SearchDirection` set to `xlPrevious` or `XLOOKUP` with the `SearchMode` set to `-1` (Perform a reverse search starting at the last item).